# webHttpBinding WCF service responds over HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, https, webhttpbinding

I am developing a WCF restfull service on my machine and when I hit the HTTP service endpoint the service responded as expected. However, when I hit the HTTPS endpoint I get a 404 Not Found back.

The Https call does not fire the `CustomAuthorizationManager` that has been implemented as the `serviceAuthorizationManagerType`

Any idea why this is not working? Why is it allowing HTTP traffic when the base address is HTTPS?

**HTTP response**
[image]

**HTTPS response**

[image]

**Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <!--Basic authentication is NOT supported when running webHttpBinding through IIS
            see - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phenning/archive/2008/01/11/custom-usernamepassword-validators-in-net-framework-3-5.aspx
            and a resolution - http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html-->
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" name="Chubb.SurveyRecommendations.Service.SurveyRecommendationsService">
        <!--webHttpBinding allows exposing service methods in a RESTful manner-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" contract="Chubb.SurveyRecommendations.Service.ISurveyRecommendations"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:44300/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Chubb.SurveyRecommendations.Service.Security.CustomAuthorizationManager, Chubb.SurveyRecommendations.Service"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <!--Required default endpoint behavior when using webHttpBinding-->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Contract**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Echo/{value}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string Echo(string value);
```

**Service**

```
public class SurveyRecommendationsService : ISurveyRecommendations
{
    public string Echo(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return string.Empty;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the problem was with the binding.

`security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"` was specified which does not provide full transport (HTTPS) secuirty.

I changed the value back to `security mode="Transport"` and it worked as anticipated.

Details can be found in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> None - Indicates no security is used with HTTP requests.
>
> Transport - Indicates that transport-level security is used with HTTP
>   requests.
>
> TransportCredentialOnly - Indicates that only HTTP-based client
>   authentication is provided.